# Pandas time-efficient, only keep (date)values in columns between two other (date)columns

Tags: python, pandas, date, python-datetime

I am trying to create a mask to only keep values(dates) that are between the dates in two other columns.

There are several dates in each row, so i want to keep all that fit the criteria, and drop all that do not. I have used forward and backwards fill on the desired range for each row, to make sure that it is easy to look up for each row.

**I have already tried to use a lambda function, which takes forever and a day to complete.** It looks like this:

```
mask0 = df[list_of_sae_dates].apply(lambda d: (d >= df['start_date'])&(d <= df['end_date']))
df = df[mask0]
```

When i try to define a mask to use in `df.loc[mask]`, it returns `'ValueError: array is too big'`

My sample data:

```
| ID | Name      | Height | start_date | end_date   | sae_1      | sae_2      | sae_3      | sae_4      |
|----|-----------|--------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
| 1  | Homestar  | 195    | 13-01-2019 | 20-01-2019 | 12-01-2019 |            | 15-01-2019 |            |
| 1  |           |        | 13-01-2019 | 20-01-2019 |            | 16-01-2019 |            | 21-01-2019 |
| 2  | Strongbad | 120    | 20-01-2019 | 25-01-2019 | 20-01-2019 |            |            |            |
| 2  |           |        | 20-01-2019 | 25-01-2019 |            |            | 22-01-2019 |            |
| 2  |           |        | 20-01-2019 | 25-01-2019 |            | 19-01-2019 |            |            |
| 3  | Steve     | 80     | 28-01-2019 | 04-02-2019 | 31-01-2019 | 04-02-2019 | 27-01-2019 |            |
| 3  |           |        | 28-01-2019 | 04-02-2019 |            |            |            |            |
| 3  |           |        | 28-01-2019 | 04-02-2019 |            | 01-02-2019 |            | 31-01-2019 |
```

My desired output:

```
| ID | Name      | Height | start_date | end_date   | sae_1      | sae_2      | sae_3      | sae_4      |
|----|-----------|--------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
| 1  | Homestar  | 195    | 13-01-2019 | 20-01-2019 |            |            | 15-01-2019 |            |
| 1  |           |        | 13-01-2019 | 20-01-2019 |            | 16-01-2019 |            |            |
| 2  | Strongbad | 120    | 20-01-2019 | 25-01-2019 | 20-01-2019 |            |            |            |
| 2  |           |        | 20-01-2019 | 25-01-2019 |            |            | 22-01-2019 |            |
| 2  |           |        | 20-01-2019 | 25-01-2019 |            |            |            |            |
| 3  | Steve     | 80     | 28-01-2019 | 04-02-2019 | 31-01-2019 | 04-02-2019 |            |            |
| 3  |           |        | 28-01-2019 | 04-02-2019 |            |            |            |            |
| 3  |           |        | 28-01-2019 | 04-02-2019 |            | 01-02-2019 |            | 31-01-2019 |
```